# Prototype Equivalent JQuery's offset()

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, offset, equivalent

I would like to know if there is any prototype equivalent to the JQuery's .offset() function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery's offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (element position relative to document) maps to [Element.cumulativeOffset](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/cumulativeoffset/)

similarly, [jQuery's position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (element position relative to offset parent) maps to [Element.positionedOffset](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/positionedoffset/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for offset relative to document, go for:

[`Element.cumulativeOffset`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/cumulativeoffset/)

If you are looking for offset relative to an element however, go for:

[`Element.Offset`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/offset/).

Comment: that link is to a class, not a method :)

Comment: @James Manning: Sorry i don't get you?

Comment: ah, the edit to include cumulativeOffset is good - when I commented the answer was just a link to Element.Offset which isn't a method (positionedOffset is the method you would use), it's a class the represents an offset (top + left)

Comment: @James Manning: Ok no problem :)